# Get Value from EditText placed in List View in android

Tags: android

I dont know how to get the the Edit text's value place in a list view.I filled the list view with data using the simpleadapter.

Will any one give sample code for getiing the edittext value from a list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < ListSortOrder.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {

        HashMap result = (HashMap)ListSortOrder.getItemAtPosition(i);       
        **View vListSortOrder;
        vListSortOrder=ListSortOrder.getChildAt(i);     

        TextView Sort_DeliveryOrder=(TextView)vListSortOrder.findViewById(R.id.et_Sort_Order);**

        initialSortOrder.put("DeliveryOrder",Sort_DeliveryOrder.getText().toString());
        dbAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
        dbAdapter.open();
        dbAdapter.BeginTransaction();
        dbAdapter.UpdateRecord("tblDelivery", initialSortOrder, "PKDelivery" + "=" + result.get("Sort_PKDelivery").toString(), null);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you already have the answer, but I will put my solution here cause I see a lot of questions without good answer.
I have a custom ArrayAdapter with the fowling code that updates the source list "telefones".

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.telefone_form, parent, false);

    tipoEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.telefone_form_tipo);
    telefoneEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.telefone_form_telefone);
    Telefone telefone = telefones.get(position);
    tipoEditText.setText(telefone.getTipo());
    telefoneEditText.setText(telefone.getTelefone());

    final int i = position;

    tipoEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            telefones.get(i).setTipo(s.toString());
        }
    });

    telefoneEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            telefones.get(i).setTelefone(s.toString());
        }
    });
```

In the Activity that sets the Adapter I get all changes with the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < telefoneListView.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
    View viewTelefone = telefoneListView.getChildAt(i);
    if (viewTelefone.findViewById(R.id.telefone_form_tipo) != null) {
        EditText tipoEditText = (EditText) viewTelefone.findViewById(R.id.telefone_form_tipo);
        EditText telefoneEditText = (EditText) viewTelefone.findViewById(R.id.telefone_form_telefone);
        Log.d(TAG, tipoEditText.getText().toString() + ":" + telefoneEditText.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

Regards, Marcello

Comment: The last part of your code was all that was necessary to be honest.  Using the for loop etc.  Thank you for the solution.

Comment: noted, about get then set text. It's simple explanation than using holder without knowing the function (`me`)

Answer (score 3):

I faced same problem but solved it. So I am sharing what I done:

- Logic: As When user fills value in EditText of listview, values with it index must be stored for future use. So,in its TouchListener create instance of ArrayList and filled it with empty value. Now when user changes its value new value is updated in last position(index stored in TouchListener) of ArrayList.

  - Problem: It also fills empty values as TouchListener called every time when user changes value in EditText.So, when ever this ArrayList used it had to remove the empty values.

  *Solution

  ```
  **In getView set tag (position) in EditText so that we can identify it on its events.

          //On TouchListner


    myEditText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
      {

      HashMap<String, String> hashMap=new HashMap<String,String>();                                  
      hashMap.put("", "");
      MyArrayList.add(hashMap);
      if(MyArrayList.size()>0)
      {
       index=MyArrayList.size()-1;
      }
      }
          }
          return false;
      }
  });

  myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

      @Override
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }

      @Override
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
              int after) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }

      @Override
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                          System.out.println(myEditText.getText().toString());
              String quanString=String.valueOf(myEditText.getTag());
              HashMap<String, String> hashMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
              hashMap.put(quanString,value);
              MyArrayList.set(index,hashMap);

      }
  });
  return listRowItemView;
      }

  //Let Suppose values had to fetch on button click--

   findViewById(R.id.submit).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  System.out.println("MyArrayList....value before removing====>"+MyArrayList);
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  for(int i=0;i<MyArrayList.size();i++)
                  {
                      HashMap<String, String> hashMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
                      hashMap= MyArrayList.get(i);
                      for (Entry<String, String> entry : hashMap.entrySet()) {
                            String key = entry.getKey();
                            String value = entry.getValue();
                            if(key.length()<=0 & value.length() <=0)
                            {
                                MyArrayList.remove(i);
                                System.out.println("At index"+i+" key value was empty so it is removes");
                                System.out.println("MyArrayList..value after removeing empty values====>"+MyArrayList);
                            }

                          }
                  }

              }
          });
  ```

Comment: nice idea, but little dirty..  maybe, i'll use it,,

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.user.listview;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView lv1;
    private EditText Et1;
    private Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        Et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ETName);
        final ArrayList<String> List = new ArrayList<>();

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String item = Et1.getText().toString();
                List.add(item);

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,List);

                lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: How is the answer provided even relevant to what the question has been asked?